# Why not an Electric Theory of Everything?

Tags: plasma-physics, theory-of-everything

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to debunk ‘The Electric Universe’?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18950/how-to-debunk-the-electric-universe)

I am just wondering why there exists such a strong feeling within the physics community against theories such as Plasma Physics and [The Electric Universe](http://www.holoscience.com/wp/).

Every single atom is governed by electromagnetic forces, molecules are formed through chemical (electromagnetic) bonds, the universe is 99% plasma which is an great conductor of electricity, the sun is made of plasma and bombards the solar system with electromagnetic energy, centers of galaxies radiate enormous amount of electromagnetic energy, etc.

It is such a simple and elegant solution that truly explains everything in a rational way which, most importantly, can be ***experimentally verified***. It can explain the true nature of mass and matter, gravity, how our sun works, how the universe works, weather systems, earthquakes, and many other phenomena that are mysteries to modern science.

So my question is: can someone explain to me why mainstream scientists are **SO** against these theories that they won't even consider them? I'm not saying they are 100% correct, but why not at least look at the theories and consider their implications?

Here are some articles I have found that explain many of the things I am talking about (no affiliation with me, I just think they well-written):

- http://www.holoscience.com/wp/sciences-looming-tipping-point
- http://www.holoscience.com/wp/a-real-theory-of-everything

Can any real physicist explain to me why these theories could not be at least plausible? I am not trying to create controversy, but merely trying to understand why they seem so outrageous.

Comment: Could you explain what the content of this theory actually is, and how it could be experimentally verified? After reading the links I don't think I can. They are mostly a list of phenomena predominantly in solar and planetary physics that cannot currently be explained, with the word 'electric' generously sprinkled throughout. To convince physicists that a new theory is correct, you must provide accurate explanations for everything we can already explain (say, hadron scattering experiments in the LHC), while also providing new predictions or a more intuitive understanding of existing ones.

Comment: On the other hand, the internet is full of people who didn't work hard enough to understand modern physics and who instead just gave up and declared it to be 'too mathematical to be true'. Since most of their predictions end up being complete rubbish, most physicists rightly ignore them without looking too deeply into what they are saying.

Comment: To give an example, [this page](http://www.holoscience.com/wp/synopsis/synopsis-11-some-basics/) of the site you linked states that nucleons are composed of charged particles in stable, classical orbits. This is in direct violation of experimentally tested laws of electrodynamics, which predict that such an orbit is unstable due to the radiation emitted by charged particles in such an orbit. This is one of the problems resolved by quantum mechanics. Any new theory that denies quantum mechanics must explain how a charged particle can be in a 'stable, classical orbit'.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18950/2451

Comment: Well, Anthony Peratt did some interesting simulations showing how electric fields in a plasma have the same exact rotation and speed as those observed in many spiral galaxies. Isn't this a better model than dark matter?

Comment: *"the universe is 99% plasma"* Current thinking is that the universe is most dark energy and that most of what remains is dark matter. Of the Baryonic matter (that's the stuff you and I are used to) the bulk is in fact plasma, but it is divided into hot dense bits and vast mostly cold low density regions.

Comment: Also, all the data coming back from our satellites and probes shows "magnetic fields" (hence electricity) in space, around the sun, around the earth, outside of the heliosphere (Voyager). In fact, everything we are seeing from new generation telescopes is electromagnetic: gamma rays, x-rays, infrared, ultraviolet, etc. So why is a force that is so much stronger than gravity and so observable by us, so quickly discounted as not a major factor that helps shape the universe around us? It's puzzling to me as a non-scientist :-)

Comment: *"Isn't this a better model than dark matter?"* Except that the star are manifestly the same kind of things as the sun. We measure their spectra and their pulsations and their masses. Such a thing is bulk neutral (we can also measure the relative strength of gravity and E&M), and if they weren't it would *show* in the spectra. These kinds of *"I'm going to reexplain everything with one simple theory"* claims usually have a hidden assumption that there are whole subfields full of blithering idiots. Perhaps it would be a good idea to talk to some of the people working in those fields.

Comment: @Andy Scientists are always trying to find a simple, unified explanation, so your impulse to find such an explanation in the Electric Universe is admirable. It's just that, as pointed out by several commenters, the theory makes a whole bunch of predictions that were proved to be completely wrong long before the guy who cooked up this theory was even born. The most important thing about scientific theories is that they are **right**, not beautiful. 

“Science is organized common sense where many a beautiful theory was killed by an ugly fact.” - TH Huxley

Comment: @dmckee: "Perhaps it would be a great idea to talk to some of the people working in those fields" - Well, that's exactly what this post is all about. I don't have access to theoretical physicists in my everyday life, this forum is one of the ways to get some feedback by people who work in those fields.

Comment: By the way, here's an interesting read, including a link to Alfvèn's nobel prize acceptance speech: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/why-were-space-physicists-wrong-about-the-location-of-the-heliopause?rq=1

Comment: Just a hint for future reference lines like *" Later, Hannes Alfvén the Swedish Nobel Prize winning physicist, with a background in electrical engineering and experience of the northern lights, drew the solar circuit."* don't say anything about an endorsement by the personality involved. It could mean *"I included some work into my theory and am now dropping names"*. That web pages makes a lot of the work of Alfvén Triumphs, but there is no actual *endorsement* there. That should set you to thinking.

Comment: Because it has no base in mathematics, and thus, can't calculate or predict anything,.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they may be cool, but what about nuclear forces? What about the standard model? I mean, it works so well, so why invent a new theory when you already have one that works so well?

EDIT: Plus the links you provided sound kinda like 'on the other side' stuff... Something that ppl who are real scientist don't like, because it's usually not testable, or are kinda far fetched...

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of hesitant to put those links for that reason, but these theories have been put forward by renowned scientists (Hannes Alfvén, Kristian Birkeland), these articles just synthesize the concepts well.